# How can I use a value of JSP in Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jsp, variables

I have a list of elements, each of them appeared in my page through jsp. So I have this:

```
<div id="title"><%= list.get(ind).getTitle() %></div>
```

When I display the elements, as this tag is in for loop, I get everything right.
Now I what to place a button for deleting each of this elements. What I have done is:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="deleteNewsFunction();" id="submit_btn"/>
```

In the deleteNewsFunction() I just want to print the data.

```
<script>
  function deleteNewsFunction(){
       var item = $('#title').val();
       alert(item);
  }
</script>
```

The problem is that the title var gets always the first item even if I am clicking on the button of the second item.
I was thinking that maybe a solution is to add the "list.get(ind).getTitle()" as a parameter in the function like deleteNewsFunction(<%=list.get(ind).getTitle()%>) but then it did not work at all.

Does anyone know how to help me?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would suggest the following:

```
<div id="title<%=ind%>"><%= list.get(ind).getTitle() %></div>
```

then

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="deleteNewsFunction(<%=ind%>);" id="submit_btn"/>
```

finally:

```
<script>
  function deleteNewsFunction(ind){
       var item = $('#title' + ind).val();
       alert(item);
  }
</script>
```